# Enable/disable button based on radio button selection in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have items in a radio button list (using `ng-repeat`) with a `button` (initially disabled with `ng-disabled`) to continue. When a radio button is selected, I want to enable the "Continue" button.

What's the right way to do this in Angular?

Relevant JS:

```
$scope.companies = [{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Twitter"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Google"
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Apple"
    }]
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="company in companies">
     <td>
       <input type="radio" ng-model="companyId" name="companyId" value="{{company.id}}" />{{company.name}}
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button ng-disabled="!companyId">Continue</button>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewboni/UZkM8/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ngRepeat creates a new scope, which is a child scope of the scope used by the button. You can fix it by using

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.companyId" .../>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/UZkM8/1/

But a better solution would be to update an object that is already in the scope:

```
$scope.userChoice = {};

<input type="radio" ng-model="userChoice.companyId" .../>

<button ng-disabled="!userChoice.companyId">Continue</button>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/UZkM8/3/

Comment: This works perfectly. Didn't realize that ng-repeat created a new scope. Thanks JB!